# How to find out whether it is Day or Night using Timestamp

Tags: python, pandas, datetime, timestamp

I want to find out whether it is day or night from the "timestamp" column in my data frame. The time stamp columns have values as follows:
20:0 , 14:30, 6:15, 5:0, 4:0 etc.

I used a for loop but it randomly generated day and night.

```
for x in data['timestamp']:
if x> '12:00':
     print('Day')

 else:
     print('Night')
```

I want a column beside my timestamp column which has values as "Day" whenever the timestamp is between 6:00am to 18:00  and "Night" when the timestamp is between 18:01 to 5:59 am.

Comment: You are not comparing times in your code, but strings, so the comparison is made in alphanumeric order.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
timestamp = ['6:00', '18:00', '18:01', '5:59']
for time in timestamp:
   hourMin = time.split(":")
   hour = int(hourMin[0])
   mint = int(hourMin[1])
   if hour>= 6 and hour <= 18:
       if(hour == 18):
           if(mint > 0):
               print("Night\n")
           else:
               print("Day\n")
       else:
           print("Day\n")
   else:
       print("Night\n")
```

Answer (score 2):

Convert values to timedeltas with [`to_timedelta`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.to_timedelta.html) and compare by [`Series.between`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.between.html), then create new column by [`numpy.where`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.where.html):

```
data = pd.DataFrame({
    'timestamp' : ['6:00', '18:00', '18:01', '5:59'],

})

mask = (pd.to_timedelta(data['timestamp'] + ':00')
          .between(pd.Timedelta('6h'),pd.Timedelta('18h')))
data['new'] = np.where(mask, 'Day', 'Night')
print (data)
  timestamp    new
0      6:00    Day
1     18:00    Day
2     18:01  Night
3      5:59  Night
```

Comment: This doesn't produce the expected result for `['6:00', '18:00', '18:01', '5:59']`.

Comment: Hi, 14:30 is not "Night" rather it is day. Can we not change the condition to display 14:30 or 12:15 or 14:45 as "Day" ?

Answer (score 0):

I'd take the hours part, parse it as int, and check if it's between 6 and 18:

```
hour = int(x.split(':'))[0]
if hour >= 6 and hour < 18:
    print('Day')
else:
    print('Night')
```

Comment: This is not entirely right, 18:00 is still day, according to the question.