# Pandas Timedelta Multiple If Condition

Tags: python, pandas, timedelta

I would like to create a new column called time_of_day for a dataframe such as below so that 06-12:59 is morning, 13-17:59 is afternoon, 18-22:59 is evening and rest of the time is night.

| id | TIME |
| --- | --- |
| 25 | 00:01 |
| 25 | 02:01 |
| 25 | 06:55 |
| 18 | 22:03 |
| 18 | 23:33 |
| 18 | 00:33 |

**What I expect**

| id | TIME | TIME_OF_DAY |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 25 | 00:01 | Night |
| 25 | 02:01 | Night |
| 25 | 06:55 | Morning |
| 18 | 22:03 | Evening |
| 18 | 23:33 | Night |
| 18 | 00:33 | Night |

I tried the numpy vectorization with choices and conditions, but it failed. Then I tried the following:

```
def conditions(s):
   if (pd.to_timedelta(df['TIME']) >= pd.to_timedelta('06:00:00')) & (pd.to_timedelta(df['TIME']) < pd.to_timedelta('13:00:00')):
       return "Morning" 
   elif (pd.to_timedelta(df['TIME']) >= pd.to_timedelta('13:00:00')) & (pd.to_timedelta(df['TIME']) < pd.to_timedelta('18:00:00')):
       return "Afternoon" 
   elif (pd.to_timedelta(df['TIME']) >= pd.to_timedelta('18:00:00')) & (pd.to_timedelta(df['TIME']) < pd.to_timedelta('23:00:00')):
       return "Evening" 
   elif (pd.to_timedelta(df['TIME']) >= pd.to_timedelta('23:00:00')) & (pd.to_timedelta(df['TIME']) < pd.to_timedelta('06:00:00')):
       return "Night" 
df['TIME_OF_DAY'] = df.apply(conditions, axis=1)
```

*ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().*

How can I overcome this issue?
PS: I added .all() for the enf od each if condition, but still got the same error.

Comment: please take a look at the answer here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56765635/how-to-find-out-whether-it-is-day-or-night-using-timestamp

Comment: @gremur I went through all pat posts, however none of them helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`pandas.cut`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.cut.html), it will be more efficient than a function with `apply`:

```
bins = ['0', '06:00:00', '13:00:00', '18:00:00', '23:00:00', '24:00:00']
labels = ['Night', 'Morning', 'Afternoon', 'Evening', 'Night']

df['TIME_OF_DAY'] = pd.cut(
  pd.to_timedelta(df['TIME']+':00'),
  bins=list(map(pd.Timedelta, bins)),
  labels=labels, right=False, ordered=False
)
```

output:

```
   id   TIME TIME_OF_DAY
0  25  00:01       Night
1  25  02:01       Night
2  25  06:55     Morning
3  18  22:03     Evening
4  18  23:33       Night
5  18  00:33       Night
```

If you need a function:

```
def to_day_period(s):
    bins = ['0', '06:00:00', '13:00:00', '18:00:00', '23:00:00', '24:00:00']
    labels = ['Night', 'Morning', 'Afternoon', 'Evening', 'Night']
    
    return pd.cut(
      pd.to_timedelta(s+':00'),
      bins=list(map(pd.Timedelta, bins)),
      labels=labels, right=False, ordered=False
    )

df['TIME_OF_DAY'] = to_day_period(df['TIME'])
```

Comment: Indeed pd.cut is way faster than apply method.

Comment: @dspractician yes, `apply` should always been seen as a last resort option when vectorization is too complex and the dataset small enough

Comment: Is there a way to twist this script so that we have bins = ['06:00:00', '13:00:00', '18:00:00', '23:00:00', '24:00:00'] ? I could not see any option to twist/change NaNs in pd.cut

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the sample DataFrame you mentioned in the question, you can make the following modifications to make the code work:

```py
def conditions(t: pd.Timedelta):
   if pd.Timestamp('06:00:00') <= t < pd.Timestamp('13:00:00'):
       return "Morning" 
   elif pd.Timestamp('13:00:00') <= t < pd.Timestamp('18:00:00'):
       return "Afternoon" 
   elif pd.Timestamp('18:00:00') <= t < pd.Timestamp('23:00:00'):
       return "Evening" 
   else:
       return "Night"

df['TIME_OF_DAY'] = df["TIME"].apply(lambda s: conditions(pd.Timestamp(s)))
```

Output (`df`):

```
   id   TIME TIME_OF_DAY
0  25  00:01       Night
1  25  02:01       Night
2  25  06:55     Morning
3  18  22:03     Evening
4  18  23:33       Night
5  18  00:33       Night
```

Answer (score 0):

```
col1=pd.cut(pd.to_datetime(df1.TIME).dt.hour,[6,13,18,23],labels=['morning','afternoon','evening'],right=False).tolist()
df1.assign(TIME_OF_DAY=col1).fillna("night")
```

out：

```
   id   TIME TIME_OF_DAY
0  25  00:01       Night
1  25  02:01       Night
2  25  06:55     Morning
3  18  22:03     Evening
4  18  23:33       Night
5  18  00:33       Night
```